# Creat a multiple mathematic statement in a case loop mysql

Tags: mysql, pivot, case, summary

I'd like to create a statement which calculates a multiple math formula. And transform the data after that.

```sql
select szallito_nev, extract(month from beerkezes_datuma) as honap,
((sum(levonas_nedvesseg_miatt)/sum(merlegelt_suly))*100) as sdf
from 2013_backup GROUP BY szallito_nev,month(beerkezes_datuma);
```

```
Company name                   month      value
A.K.S.D. VÁROSGAZDÁLKODÁSI KFT  1   1.542938202451533
A.K.S.D. VÁROSGAZDÁLKODÁSI KFT  2   2.085091455775495
A.K.S.D. VÁROSGAZDÁLKODÁSI KFT  3   3.7353360231161536
A.K.S.D. VÁROSGAZDÁLKODÁSI KFT  4   1.979149061085067
```

if I make this it works well but its shows the summary vertically and I want to transform it into horizontally so I tried this one:

```sql
select szallito_nev,
(case extract(month from beerkezes_datuma) when '1' then ((sum(levonas_nedvesseg_miatt)/sum(merlegelt_suly))*100)   else 0 end) as 'H1'
from 2013_backup group by szallito_nev with rollup
```

```
company name                         Januar
A.K.S.D. VÁROSGAZDÁLKODÁSI KFT         0
A.S.A. MAGYARORSZÁG KFT.               0
ASCO HUNGARIA KFT                      0
```

but after this I've got different results.

Answer (score 1):

I will show you an idea -

```
SELECT
  szallito_nev,
  SUM(IF(month = 1, VALUE, NULL)) Jan,
  SUM(IF(month = 2, VALUE, NULL)) Feb,
  SUM(IF(month = 3, VALUE, NULL)) Mar,
  SUM(IF(month = 4, VALUE, NULL)) Apr
FROM
  -- this is a place for your subquery
  (SELECT szallito_nev...) t
GROUP BY
  szallito_nev
```

Comment: you mean the calculation will be placed after the from?

Comment: Yes, in this example the SUM is used as one of the aggregate functions.

Comment: but my problem is that the value field is comming from the calculation and if i write the hole formula inside the if statemant i ve got an error like "invalid use of group function"

Comment: No, all your calculations have to be inside the subquery. The SUM in main query can be replaced with another aggregate function, it does not matter which to use.

Comment: ahh okay i understand and what does the t stand for ?

Comment: In MySQL this aggregate function can be ommited, but for SQL standard it is needed.

Comment: Can you add CREATE TABLE, INSERT INTO statements with data?

Comment: its a litte bit difficult becouse theres a table which is already created and after i load an csv into it and after i convert it into the right format and finaly make the calculations from the converted table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  sz_nev,
  IF( datum = 1, ossz, NULL) Jan

from (
    (select szallito_nev as sz_nev from hamburger) a,
    (select extract(month from beerkezes_datuma) as datum from hamburger) b,
    (select ((sum(levonas_nedvesseg_miatt)/sum(merlegelt_suly))*100) as ossz FROM hamburger) c
   )
group by sz_nev with rollup
```

i'll tried this one but it never runs over just executing in progress and never done:S is this way that slow? or what should be the problem?